# Firefox - how to refresh an open tab automatically every x minutes?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

can someone help please in the following situation:

You have multiple tabs open in Firefox. While you are surfing across different tabs, you would like a specific tab (tab "A") to refresh itself automatically every X minutes (should be sth between 2 & 5 minutes).

Is sth like this possible with Firefox?  I remember that there was in the past an option to auto refresh a tab, but I do not see that option anymore (when right-clicking on a tab).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [allow-pages-autorefresh-reload-firefox](https://itstillworks.com/allow-pages-autorefresh-reload-firefox-21805.html)
For quick reference-

> Firefox Advanced Options
>
> You can enable the auto-refresh from Firefox Advanced Options by clicking the orange Firefox button on the top left corner of the browser and then clicking "Options." From the list of options, select "Advanced." Under the "General" tab, in the "Accessibility" section, you will be able to remove the check mark next to "Warn me when websites try to redirect or reload the page" to allow the auto-refresh or reload feature.
>
> Firefox About Config
>
> You can also configure Firefox manually by entering "about:config" in the browser's address bar. A warning message will appear; click on "I'll be careful, I promise!" to be able to continue. Next, type "Accessibility.blockautorefresh" in the search box at the top of the page. Double-click the "true" value next to this preference to set it to "false" and allow the browser pages to auto-refresh.

Comment: I think this option is only to allow web pages that want to auto refresh themselves to do so.  The default is to not allow it if the tab isn't active.  I think the real answer is to use one of the extensions mentioned below.

Answer (score 5):

You can find different Extention on `Firefox Browser Add-on` for auto-refresh tab

Get as per your requirement

check this two Extention for auto-refresh:

[Tab Auto Refresh](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-auto-refresh/)

[Tab Reloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-reloader/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free Firefox addon which can do what your asking

Tab Auto Refresh

> [About this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-auto-refresh/)
>
> Tab Auto Refresh is a Firefox addon that helps you automatically reload tabs of your choice.
>
> In order to operate with this addon, please open toolbar popup UI while you are visiting a website. Adjust time interval in seconds (i.e. 120 sec) and you are all set. Selected tab will be reloaded based on the interval you just set.
>
> Please note reloading occurs based on tab URL not tab ID or domain. If you want to stop the current "reload" task, please press on the "stop" button at top left corner in toolbar popup UI. Alternatively you can set the interval to 0 which is equal to stop function.
>
> If you have many tabs reloading and do not want to visit each tab to clear the reloading task, please open toolbar popup UI and press on the "reset" (top right) button to do so. This button serves as a global reset button and clears the reloading task for all tabs.